# What's the difference between "as" and "when" in the following situation?

Tags: word-choice

> **As** I reached the middle of the bridge, I spotted someone leaning on the railing.
>
> **When** I reached the middle of the bridge, I spotted someone leaning on the railing.

What's the difference between the two sentences? Or they mean exactly the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two subordinate conjunctions have very similar meanings in this context. I believe "as" implies more of a continuous span of time, whereas "when" implies more of a precise moment in time.

"As I reached the middle of the bridge, I spotted..." implies that I began to spot the person when I was *in the course of reaching* the middle of the bridge.

"When I reached the middle of the bridge, I spotted..." implies that I *first* reached the middle of the bridge and *then immediately* spotted the person.

Comment: I can't find any difference in dictionaries, but my intuition is that "as" is more likely to indicate a moment, while you can use "when" with extended or repeated time intervals: "I knew him when we were at school together", "When I go running I carry a water bottle" - neither works with "as". In the OP's case, either is fine because it's a single moment.